# UDP not being recieved in mono on a Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, c#

The code fragment below works happily under windows and using mono under ubuntu, but for a raspberry pi the ReceiveHandler is called for TCP but not for UDP which are broadcast messages.  Any clues would be useful.  I have confirmed there is no firewall and the addresses are correct, including network masks.

```
 public void StartAsynchronousReceive()
    {
      m_waitFrom = DateTime.UtcNow;
      if (RemoteEndPoint == null)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting tcp async receive on " + BaseSocket.LocalEndPoint.Serialize());
        // BeginReceive is used for connection orientated sockets (TCP)
        BaseSocket.BeginReceive(
          Buffer,
          BufferOffset,
          Buffer.Length - BufferOffset,
          SocketFlags.None,
          ReceiveHandler,
          this);
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting udp async receive on " + BaseSocket.LocalEndPoint.Serialize());
        // BeginReceiveFrom is used for connectionless sockets (UDP)
        BaseSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(
          Buffer,
          BufferOffset,
          Buffer.Length - BufferOffset,
          SocketFlags.None,
          ref RemoteEndPoint,
          ReceiveHandler,
          this);
      }
    }
    private void ReceiveHandler(IAsyncResult pResult)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Async ReceiveHandler called");
    }
```

Comment: All programming questions are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: Sorry it is out of scope.  This is my first question here and it looks like it got in the wrong section.  Can you tell me how to move it?

Comment: First try a direct message, not broadcast.